# how to get the name of a class variable

Tags: python, string, class, oop, instance

Suppose I have the following codes:

```
lens_A = Lens(...) # declare an object of type 'Lens' called 'lens_A'
table = Bench() # declare an object 'Bench' called 'table'
table.addcomponent(lens_A, 10) 

addcomponent(self, component, position): # a method inside the class Bench
    self.__component_class.append(component)
    self.__component_position.append(position)
    self.__component_name.append(...) # how to do this????
```

I want to write the last line such that I can add the name of the class variable ('lensA') to the list `self.__component_name`, but not the location of the instance (which is done in `self.__component_class`). How to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Instead you could have a name property as a part of the `Lens` class and refer to that.

Comment: Objects don't intrinsically have names. What should happen if you do `table.addcomponent(Lens(...), 10)`?

Comment: If you say `lens_A = lens_B = Lens()`, which name is right.

Comment: so other than adding an extra property to the class, there are no ways to get the 'words' (which is 'lensA') that I type for the argument 'component' of the method?

Comment: Exactly. In fact, for most programming languages, the cases where names of things are observable at execution time are exceptional. The general rule is often that (when done according to the binding semantics of the language) name changes don't change the behaviour of the program.

Comment: This or similar questions have been asked a number of times here, search around and see what solutions were offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it but it may not be practical and this may not work depending on the scope where it is executed.  It seems like a hack and not the correct way to solve the problem.

```
# locals() might work instead of globals()
>>> class Foo(object):
    pass

>>> lion = Foo()
>>> zebra = Foo()
>>> zebra, lion
(<__main__.Foo object at 0x02F82CF0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x03078FD0>)
>>> for k, v in globals().items():
    if v in (lion, zebra):
        print 'object:{} - name:{}'.format(v, k)


object:<__main__.Foo object at 0x03078FD0> - name:lion
object:<__main__.Foo object at 0x02F82CF0> - name:zebra
>>>
```